# Unwanted chars are added after saving string to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, peewee, flask-peewee

I need to update an existing entry in my MySQL database with the help of peewee and experienced a quite weird issue.

When I save a number as a string, some new chars will be added after I saved it.

For example when I run the below code:

```
obj = mydbtable.get(mydbtable.zid == zid)
myval = "10"
obj.myfield = myval
obj.save()
```

I get the following string in my PhpMyAdmin:

```
(10,)
```

So the value of `myval` will be `(10,)` after saving instead of `10`.

Honestly I have no idea what causes this issue, because I have done the same saving task several times and worked like a charm always. I tried to pass the variable even as an `int` but got the same.

### Update

Right after saving `obj`, calling the below method fixes the problem, but this workaround is a bit overkill and not the most elegant solution:

```
    objy = mydbtable.get(mydbtable.zid == zid)
    ooo = objy.myfield
    objy.myfield = ooo.replace(',','').replace(')','').replace('(','').replace("'","")
    objy.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're assigning a tuple to the field instead of a string or number. I'm not sure where your source data is coming from but check for trailing commas if nothing else.